# is it possible to show both image and video in rich notification iOS swift?

Tags: ios, firebase, apple-push-notifications

I am only able to attach either image or video not both.Is it possible to show video and image both

Answer (score 1):

No I’m afraid not. If you think of the space available on an iOS notification there’s only 1 slot for an image. So, you have two problems. First, videos won’t play in an iOS notification. Second, you can only send one at a time.

If you’re sending the notification from a cloud function a possible solution would be to send two notifications. The first with the image attached and a short description ending in ‘1/2’. Then the second with the video and description and ending with a ‘2/2’ to indicate they’re the same message but split into two.